# Select de duas tabelas e inserir em outras duas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho quatro tabelas

```
tabela A  aic002
campos :
codigo data nome especie valor rg cpf exped

Tabela B excli
campos
codigo nome rg cpf exped


tabela C imovel
Campos
codigo imovel rua bairro cidade estado 

tabela D  escritura 
codigo  data especie valor  rua bairro cidade estado
```

Eu gostaria de executar um único `insert` que:

- pegaria  os campos (data especie valor) DE A e popularia em D que seria a tabela de controle de escrituras
- pegar campos (nome rg cpf exped ) de A e popularia em B criando assim uma nova tabela de clientes
- pegar  (rua bairro cidade estado) de C e popularia em D para completar os enderecos dos clientes

Como fazer isso em um único `insert` sabendo-se que:

As tabelas A, B e C estão relacionadas por código mas a única que não se repete o código é a Imovel Tabela C.

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você quer não é possível com apenas um `insert`, é preciso pelo menos dois já que duas tabelas serão escritas. Não está claro como o relacionamento está sendo feito. Você diz o que pega, mas pega como? Pega as colunas especificadas. Como saber qual é a linha? BTW seu nome é Marcos ou Joelias?

Comment: É Joelias Marcos. é que eu queria fazer o insert sem precisar depois efetuar um update em uma das tabela ja populadas que noo caso seria tabela d escritura.Entao pelo que entendi serei obrigado a fazer o update...

Comment: Não esta certo mas acho que é o caminho...

Comment: QUando você for adicionar informações, faça edição na pergunta e deixe tudo organizado. Eu dei uma melhorada porque a pergunta estava bem bagunçada. No comentário fica mais difícil ler alguma coisa e entender.

Comment: insert into escrituras (TipoImovelDescr,RUA,BAIRRO,MUNICIPIO,UF) 
select DISTINCT
a.DESCRICAO,a.RUA,a.BAIRRO,a.CIDADE,a.ESTADO
from 
 imovel a    
INNER JOIN escrituras  b on a.LIVRO = 'E0285155'
INNER JOIN aic002  c on a.LIVRO = c.CODIGO
group by a.LIVRO (rodo o select mas não me retorna nada no select)

Answer (score 1):

Joelias,

Como comentaram, não é possível realizar o que você deseja com apenas um ***INSERT*** pois temos dois destinos a serem inseridos (B, D) mas creio que o seu objetivo é evitar o uso do ***UPDATE*** na tabela D. Tente o seguinte:

```
    INSERT INTO D(data, especie, valor, rua, bairro, cidade, estado)        
    SELECT A.data, A.especie, A.valor        
         , C.rua, C.bairro, C.cidade, C.estado        
      FROM A        
      JOIN C ON C.codigo = A.codigo        

    INSERT INTO B(nome, rg, cpf, exped)        
    SELECT A.nome, A.rg, A.cpf, A.exped FROM A
```

Veja que não inseri nos inserts a coluna referente aos códigos pois não ficou claro se o código é ***PRIMARY KEY*** (PK) ou ***FOREIGN KEY*** (FK). Pelo que entendi ela é uma FK. Se for, você deve inserí-las na inserção como fizemos com as outras colunas.

Comment: Muito obrigado Vinicius , vou testar e te retorno se ok...